# How can I achieve parallelism in a program that is writing to the disk in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, disk

I have a buffer in main memory that contains a couple of files that I want to write in parallel(if possible?) to the disk. I read and write to different location every time.

This is my code:

```
#include <thread>
void t1(){//read from the buffer and writes the 1st file to the disk }
void t2(){//same with the second one }
void t3(){//3rd}
void t4(){//4th}

int main(){
  std::thread thread1(t1);
  std::thread thread2(t2);
  std::thread thread3(t3);
  std::thread thread4(t4);

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();
}
```

I know that I can do in parallel the reading of the buffer but the write is the bottleneck. Is there I way that I parallelise the write to the disk? Is there anything else that I can do to have better performance ?

Thanks

EDIT: Every thread is writing to a different file.

Comment: Since you are not doing direct I/O, the OS tunes and re-orders these writes to be the most efficient, there is not a lot your code will be able to do to improve this(unless you're doing parallell read/writes to the same file). Use SSD disks, or set up disks in RAID ?

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to indicate whether a) all threads are writing to the same file, or to different files.  b)  If they are writing to the same file, does each thread have it's own "region" of that file it is writing to.

Comment: @nos I already use SSD disks. So there is no way I can write at the same time from different threads on different cores to the disk ?

Comment: @MartinBonner different files I edited. Thanks

Comment: @mata Doesn't your program already write at the same time from different threads ? The OS will take care of getting the most performance out of your hard drive. There's just not more your code can do to improve performance, (except in this case to set up several drives in a RAID configuration, so the system can access different drives in parallel as long as they are connected to buses and bus controllers that can drive them in parallel. (Also keep in mind that writing from an application to a file just writes into a memory buffer, and the OS will at is leisure commit it to disk later on)

Comment: It seems you hope to achieve better performance by writing in parallel. Keep in mind, that all access to your drive happens over a common hardware bus and all you can hope for is to saturate that bus. If each of your threads can saturate the write bandwidth on its own, you can not hope to increase performance any further. In that case, having multiple threads can probably even lead to congestion issues.

Comment: @nos: a RAID configuration would be counter-productive, as that gives up up the control over the physical distribution. If you have 4 disks mounted as `/disk1` to `/disk4`, you can guarantee each thread writes to a distinct disk. If you instead have 4 threads all writing to `/raid`, it will be at the whim of the filesystem to choose logical blocks, and there's no expectation for them to be equally distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It very much depends on the data you want to write.

Writing fixed-sized data you could split it up into four chunks, and each thread seeks to a specific position in the file and write there. Note that you need four different file stream objects, one per thread.

Writing data without a fixed size, like arbitrary text, is not possible to do in parallel. You need some kind of synchronization for this so only one thread writes at a time.

Also, even if the data is a fixed size, it might not be possible to write in parallel, if the data is streaming and can't be split up into chunks.

---

The above is if you want all threads to write to the *same* file. If the threads each write to different files then it's no problem. That's no different that multiple processes writing to different files.

Comment: @mata On your computer there are multiple programs running in parallel right this instance, and some of them are writing to your disk as you read this text. Having four different threads in which each of them open their own file and write to them is no different. This is what part of the operating system you use was designed to handle.

Comment: do I need to do something else or the code I wrote above already does the writes in parallel ?  And how can I mesure in Visual Studio Community 2015 how much time it takes to execute one thread and the time it take to execute the whole program ?

Comment: @mata If you open a file in each thread and write to it, then it will work as you expect.

Comment: You said that I can write in parallel from different threads. But I saw this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254147/writing-data-to-disk-in-parallel   and now I'm really confused. Does the OS use only one thread to write to the disk ? If yes then it means that it's not possible to write in parallel :(

Comment: @mata Try it, measure it, and then decide. Operating systems are very good at handling these sort of things. Remember, multiple processes and programs, each with a least one thread of execution, can simultaneously write to the same disk without problem. Will it be slower? Maybe. Will it be faster? Maybe. You can't know until you try. Also, spinning-disc hard-drives are getting rarer by the day, an SSD don't have the problems with positioning.